# Getting 5 random crops - TypeError: pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got <type ‘tuple’>

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch, vision

I do transformations on images as below (which works with RandCrop): (it is from this dataloader script: https://github.com/jeffreyhuang1/two-stream-action-recognition/blob/master/dataloader/motion_dataloader.py)

```
def train(self):
training_set = motion_dataset(dic=self.dic_video_train, in_channel=self.in_channel, root_dir=self.data_path,
mode=‘train’,
transform = transforms.Compose([
transforms.Resize([256,256]),
transforms.FiveCrop([224, 224]),
#transforms.RandomCrop([224, 224]),
transforms.ToTensor(),
#transforms.Normalize([0.5], [0.5])
]))
print ‘==> Training data :’,len(training_set),’ videos’,training_set[1][0].size()

    train_loader = DataLoader(
        dataset=training_set, 
        batch_size=self.BATCH_SIZE,
        shuffle=True,
        num_workers=self.num_workers,
        pin_memory=True
        )

    return train_loader
```

But when I do try to get Five Crops, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “motion_cnn.py”, line 267, in 
main()
File “motion_cnn.py”, line 51, in main
train_loader,test_loader, test_video = data_loader.run()
File “/media/d/DATA_2/two-stream-action-recognition-master/dataloader/motion_dataloader.py”, line 120, in run
train_loader = self.train()
File “/media/d/DATA_2/two-stream-action-recognition-master/dataloader/motion_dataloader.py”, line 156, in train
print ‘==> Training data :’,len(training_set),’ videos’,training_set[1][0].size()
File “/media/d/DATA_2/two-stream-action-recognition-master/dataloader/motion_dataloader.py”, line 77, in getitem
data = self.stackopf()
File “/media/d/DATA_2/two-stream-action-recognition-master/dataloader/motion_dataloader.py”, line 51, in stackopf
H = self.transform(imgH)
File “/media/d/DATA_2/two-stream-action-recognition-master/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py”, line 60, in call
img = t(img)
File “/media/d/DATA_2/two-stream-action-recognition-master/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py”, line 91, in call
return F.to_tensor(pic)
File “/media/d/DATA_2/two-stream-action-recognition-master/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py”, line 50, in to_tensor
raise TypeError(‘pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got {}’.format(type(pic)))
TypeError: pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got <type ‘tuple’>
```

Getting 5 random crops, I should handle a tuple of images instead of a PIL image - so I use Lambda, but then I get the error, at line 55, in stackopf
flow[2*(j),:,:] = H

> RuntimeError: expand(torch.FloatTensor{[5, 1, 224, 224]}, size=[224,
>   224]): the number of sizes provided (2) must be greater or equal to
>   the number of dimensions in the tensor (4)

and when I try to set flow = torch.FloatTensor(5, 2*self.in_channel,self.img_rows,self.img_cols)

I get motion_dataloader.py", line 55, in stackopf
flow[:,2*(j),:,:] = H

> RuntimeError: expand(torch.FloatTensor{[5, 1, 224, 224]}, size=[5,
>   224, 224]): the number of sizes provided (3) must be greater or equal
>   to the number of dimensions in the tensor (4)

when I multiply the train batchsize by 5 that is returned, I also get the same error.